# Better scala style

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I'm a python/go coder and new to scala. I have a working piece of code with if and else, but any suggestions on writing it the "scala" way?

```
if (sp.bin_an.size() > 0) {
  sp.bin_an.asScala.toList.foreach { an =>
  if (an.host != null && an.host.name != "" && an.routine == "xx") {
    service = an.host.name
  }
}
```

Comment: [CodeReview.SE]; https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#find

Comment: @Ryan: Could you help elaborate?

Comment: What is the type of `sp.bin_an`?

Comment: @jwvh list of objects(with attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you can avoid checking size by just doing `map` or `foreach`- if collection is empty just nothing is gonna happen. Try to avoid variables like service. You better assign result of filtering to val

`val service = sp.bin_an.asScala.toList.filter(an => an.host != null && an.host.name != "" && an.routine == "xx").map { an => an.host.name}`

And maybe .toList conversion is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

instead of `list.foreach(x => if(cond) action)` you can do a filter and then foreach like `list.filter(cond).foreach(x => action)`

so your above example can be re-written as

```
sp.bin_an.asScala.toList.filter(an => an.host != null && an.host.name != "" && an.routine == "xx").foreach()
```